# Why is this estimator biased?

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution, bias

$X_{1},X_{2},..,X_{n}$ are iid $\sim Poisson(\mu)$

than the MLE for $\theta=e^{-\mu}$ is $\hat \theta =e^{-\bar x}$

Why is this considered to be biased for $\theta$?

Is $E[\hat \theta]$ not $\theta$ ?

as

$E[\bar x]= \mu$

Comment: E[f(X)] != f(E[X]) in general.

Comment: I know that general result but I am still confused how to do it here since the sum of poisson is also poisson with mean $n \mu$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that the moment generating function of $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu)$ is
$$
E[e^{s X}] = \exp(\mu(e^s - 1))
$$
for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$

*Proof.*
We just compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[e^{s X}]
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{s k} e^{-\mu} \frac{\mu^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\mu} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\mu e^s\right)^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\mu} e^{\mu e^s} \\
&= \exp(\mu(e^s - 1)).
\end{aligned}
$$
We will use this result with $s = -1/n$.

If $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu)$ are i.i.d. and
$$
\widehat{\theta}
= \exp\left(-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
= \prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(-\frac{X_i}{n}\right),
$$
then, using independence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[\widehat{\theta}]
&= \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[e^{-X_i / n}\right] \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \exp(\mu(e^{-1/n} - 1)) \\
&= \exp(n \mu(e^{-1/n} - 1)) \\
&\neq e^{-\mu},
\end{aligned}
$$
so $\widehat{\theta}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $e^{-\mu}$

Answer (score 10):

As an aside from finding the exact expectation, you can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), which says that for a random variable $X$ and a convex function $g$,

$$E\left[g(X)\right]\ge g\left(E\left[X\right]\right)$$

, provided the expectations exist.

Verify that $g(x)=e^{-x}$ is a convex function from the fact that $g''>0$.

The equality does not hold because $g$ is not an affine function or a constant function.